# Drupal views - 2 latest reports and related content

Tags: views

My Drupal site contains a certain type of report, and these reports sometimes have 1 or more amendments, which will have field_related_content pointing to the report they're amending.

I'm trying to set up a view that will display the latest two reports, plus any amendments to those reports, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

Can Views filters refer to results from other filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create view in a view using View Field View (https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view):

- Create a view of reports
- Create a view of amendments which takes a contextual filter of node id and filters amendments which have a field reference with that node id value
- Put the view amendments view in a view of reports as a field (using above mentioned module - see it's documentation for more specific info if necessary)

Btw. just a thought - isn't it possible for you to switch the architecture and have the node reference field in the document content type, referencing the amendments? - this way you wouldn't need a view in a view and it would be easier to display it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out that module.  It is possible to switch, but that's a crummy workflow since the amendments typically come out later than the reports.  The desired workflow is to create an amendment and link it to the original report, which is easier than creating an amendment and then going back and editing the original report to reference the new amendment.